# The heat energy per unit mass required to raise the temperature of a thin slice of material

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics

Suppose that the specific heat of a material is a function of position and temperature, $ c(x,u) $. Show that the heat energy per unit mass necessary to raise the temperature of a thin slice of thickness $ \Delta x $ from $ 0 $ to $ u(x,t) $ is not $ c(x) u(x,t) $ but $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{u(x,t)} c(x,\overline{u}) ~ \mathrm{d}{\overline{u}} $ instead.

Can somebody help me out with this question? What is $ c(x,\overline{u}) $ for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think about the heat energy per unit mass necessary to raise the temperature as sum of all heat energies per unit mass for temperatures from 0 to $u$ as temperatures rise in small steps. This is

$$\sum_{i=0}^u c(x,i) \Delta i$$

where $\Delta i = u/n$ is the change in temperature. I've given the summation variable an arbitrary name $i$. But we could think of $i$ as the mean temperature in the small step and write $i=\bar{u}$ instead. So the following is equivalent

$$\sum_{\bar{u}=0}^u c(x,i) \Delta \bar{u}$$

You can see that $\bar{u}$ is just a summation variables. Hopefully you can see how this might turn into an integral? But can you see why an integral is necessary?

The specific heat is a function of position $x$ and temperature $u$. But why do we have to do a summation over the temperature but not over the position? The clue is that we're told that we have a *thin* slice, but nothing is said about the temperature range.

Comment: Can you say that we choose the steps ($\Delta \overline{u}$) infinitely small so the summation becomes a integral?

Comment: @RoosJansen yes, exactly that. Can you see _why_ we need a sum or an integral and we can't just multiply by the temperature change? (Think about a car that's accelerating over a journey. Can you use distance = speed * time?)

Comment: Becuase $c(x)$ isn't constant but changes if the position $x$ changes?

Comment: @RoosJansen Yes nearly there. It does change if the position changes, but what's changing here? Is the position change or the temperature changing (or both)? What clues are you given in the question about what stays the same and what changes? See last para of my answer.

Comment: I think the position x is changing and the temperature isn't.

Comment: @RoosJansen you're told the slice is _thin_. How much is the position going to change in a thin slice? And do you know if the temperature is raised a little or a lot?

Comment: Oh, the position change is thus very small and the change of temperature is u(x,t). So we need the integral because c(x,u) isn't constant, but depeds on the change of u.

Comment: Yes you got it :)

Comment: @RoosJansen glad to have helped and I learnt something by revising this stuff. If my answer solved your problem, you can "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it (you can also upvote if you wish). Accepting scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).